# Can’t change the “CALCULATE VAT” logic of following php application

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can’t change the “CALCULATE VAT” logic of following php application

Here I am dealing with an inventory management system. I downloaded an open source project from the web. I want to edit/remove the VAT feature from this project. I changed the way of calculating vat from this,

```
// vat
var vat = (Number($("#subTotal").val())/100) * 13;
vat = vat.toFixed(2);
$("#vat").val(vat);
$("#vatValue").val(vat);

// total amount
var totalAmount = (Number($("#subTotal").val()) + Number($("#vat").val()));
totalAmount = totalAmount.toFixed(2);
$("#totalAmount").val(totalAmount);
$("#totalAmountValue").val(totalAmount);
```

to this

```
// vat
var vat = (Number($("#subTotal").val())/100) * 2;
vat = vat.toFixed(2);
$("#vat").val(vat);
$("#vatValue").val(vat);

// total amount
var totalAmount = (Number($("#subTotal").val()) + Number($("#vat").val()));
totalAmount = totalAmount.toFixed(2);
$("#totalAmount").val(totalAmount);
$("#totalAmountValue").val(totalAmount);
```

but it's always calculating 13% of VAT. Please help me solve this problem.

Comment: First of all, this is JS you're showing and second, if it's an open source project, can you provide us the github or project name? So other people can help try to find out how to fix your issue

Comment: Stock Inventory System

Comment: you probably need to provide some more information.  Immediate things to do would be some console logging to ensure you're changing the vat in the right place.  I/We assume you are saying it doesn't work on the front end, but if it's not working on the back end then you'd need to look at the back end code.   An open source project probably uses a compiled minified js - Have you re-compiled the code? Have you read the documentation of your open source project? It's unlikely you're the first person to want to change the vat value, have you googled how to change your specific open source VAT?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to calculate VAT dynamically then add an input

```
<input type="text" value="0" id="vat-percentage" name="vat-percentage" />
```

and then replace this

```
var vat = (Number($("#subTotal").val())/100) * 13;
```

with that

```
var vat = (Number($("#subTotal").val())/100) * Number($('#vat-percentage').val());
```

Comment: I want to change the 13% vat into 0.